# NextJS revalidatePath doesn't apply to layout components

Tags: prisma, next.js13

I am using NextJS with App Directory enabled, and I am having a hard time getting a layout component to revalidate without actually refreshing the browser window.

The component is for a profile avatar/name on my nav bar. The component is fetching data through a Prisma server action. The page is also using the same exact server action to get the same data so a user can update details. On successful update in Prisma, I am calling to revalidate the path:

```
await prisma.profile.update({ .... }); 
revalidatePath('/profile');
```

This is successfully updating the record, and revalidating page.tsx, but the layout component continues to be stale.

I know in the [documentation it says](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts#layouts) that layouts do not "re-render during navigation", but I am confused as to how to solve for dynamic content in a component like the nav bar.

Comment: The nav bar is a server Component right ?

Have you tried, router.refresh() after calling revalidatePath('/profile');

Comment: @Hashira, the layout component is a client one. The page is a server component. The update action is being called from the page. I tried router.refresh() from the page as well, but it's still not refreshing the layout components for me.

Comment: You know the moment you made the layout a client component, you have also made every child of the layout a client component too.

I have an idea, i will drop it as an answer

Comment: If layout client component. use template instead - https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/template